# Redirected to www, but Google is indexing no-www without snippets, should I use noindex instead?

Tags: htaccess, redirects, canonical-url, noindex, no-www

I started my blog a month ago and was using non www version for my website.

Then, I recently decided to stick to `www.example.com` version. So I changed it and Google has indexed the `www` version properly if I search `www.example.com` in Google search, I can see the meta description and title that I use.

I also added a redirect in *.htaccess* based on my research from a Google search:

```
# ADDING CHANGES FOR NON WWW TO WWW REDIRECT
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
# END
```

Now the problem is my non `www` version is also showing up in Google search and it does not have any meta description etc and basically wrong. So what do I need to do with non `www` version of site?

Do I need to do a `noindex`? But where would I put it? (I don't have separate page for no-www).

Comment: Do each of your pages contain a `<link rel="canonical" href="https://www.[…]" />` ?

Comment: How long ago did you implement the redirect?

Comment: Welcome to Webmasters! If you are properly redirecting non-www to www using a 301, then all you have to do is be patient. Google is notoriously slow. Be patient and it will all work out. We webmasters want our sites to be successful soon if not today or tomorrow. The problem is, creating a website is an exercise in patience - it is a slow process. Take this time to keep working on your site and know that if you do your work well, your site will succeed as it should. Cheers!!

Comment: "it does not have **any meta description** etc" - Can you show a screenshot please? What search query are you using? Are you perhaps using a `site:` search?